# Regex split by character and capture

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

I'm looking for a regular expression to split and capture a url path eg with example.com/param1/param2/param3 I would like param1, param2 and param3 to be captured. There could be an unknown number of parameters. This will be used with PHP's preg_match. Can this be done?

EDIT:
This will be used with PHP's preg_match, because I am using it as a Zend Router Rule. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex if it's always going to be a `/`, you could just explode it into an array:

```
$array = explode('/', $url);
```

Comment: I'm looking for a regex to use in a Zend Router rule, so i'm limited to using a single regex expression to match and capture the relevant parameters. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if it allows it

```
(/[^/]*)+
```

That'll give multiple matches /param1, /param2, /param3

Then just strip the slashes